# Is it possible to angle the wheels on Speed Champions?

Tags: building, vehicle, wheel

I have got quite a few Speed Champions sets and I like building MOCs to photograph them in. However, I feel like the photos would look more dynamic if I could angle the front wheels, to look like some steering lock has been applied.

These sets mostly use a Technic 1L axle pin, but can you get an angled equivalent? Even if it doesn’t allow for the wheel to rotate.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you could potentially replace the axle pin with a [technic half pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4274) and some thick wire (~3.18mm ⌀) bent into the right shape. This _may_ allow the wheels to rotate still

Answer (score 3):

For your photography use case, it may not be necessary to attach the wheels. Simply remove the Technic pin and position the wheel as desired. Here's a quick example:

[image: Photo with angled front wheel]

Comment: I have tried that, but struggled to get the wheel looking centred in the wheel arch, so was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: @LC1983 In order to keep the wheel in the correct position in relation to the wheel arch you would need a pivot point that is directly underneath the center of the arch and just about in between the (visible part) of the arched piece and the 2 curved slopes on the inside of the arch. That is INSIDE the actual hub of the wheel itself. There is simply no room for any Lego piece to go there. The geometry of small Lego wheels is not quite the same as that on real cars. Bigger Lego wheels (and suspension parts) do better in that regard.